# High-res iPad icon in Flex/Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, ipad, flash-builder

Apple says that a 144x144 application icon is [now required](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) for the high-res iPad. But adding an `<image144x144>` element to the application descriptor file in Flex 4.6 gives an `error 103: application.icon.image144x144 is an unexpected element/attribute`.

Is there a workaround for this? Perhaps through the iPhone InfoAdditions area of the application descriptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming across this question, [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4273813#4273813) suggests that Adobe needs to release an update to support the larger icon size, and that the user Colin Holgate will post if he hears news about it from Adobe.

Comment: So any AIR app that targets the iPad is going to be rejected because of the missing icon?

Comment: Ours was accepted without the icon. There may be a grace period before it's enforced.

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding `<image144x144>` under the `<icon>` tag in the xxx-app.xml file? It works OK for me. I have had problems with icons with transparent pixels but, normally, uncommenting the `<icon>` section works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Eduardo. Yes, my appname-app.xml looks like the following:


`<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.1">
<icon>
<image144x144>/path/to/img.png</image144x144>
</icon>
</application>`


Other sizes (57x57, 114x114, etc.) work correctly.

Comment: Can you specifically confirm that the 144x144 size is working for you? That's the only size that isn't working for me.

Comment: Sorry Dan, I got confused with 114x114. No, I have not been able to use 144x144. If you are looking to develop for the new iPad, check out the following (which you might have seen from Adobe's forums, and which does not address the 144x144): http://www.richardlord.net/blog/using-the-ipad-retina-display-with-adobe-air